# UITableView got lag when scroll to larger row number

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView that each of its cell has a same-size UIImageView as contentView's subView.

When I scroll it, at the beginning, it was quite smooth,but when it comes to larger row number, almost 50 row or more, the FPS become lower than 30,and the larger the row is ,the lower fps become.

I checked that there is no memory leak.

I‘m wondering if this is a common phenomenon?

Comment: Are you queuing up the cells and reusing them as necessary?

Comment: @PaulMason Yes, I did it in proper way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely, you are doing something like `[cellView addSubview:mySubview];` in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, irrespective of whether that cell was just created or re-used. The subviews are being stacked up leading to the problem that you are seeing.